# Spring component scan for beans with no no-args constructor

Tags: java, spring

```
@Component
public class StringConsumer {

@Autowired
MessageConsumer messageConsumer;


public void m1(Channel channel) {

//MessageConsumer messageConsumer=new MessageConsumer(channel);
//how to use spring to do this, initialize MessageConsumer with channel instance value for this class.

}   
}

@Component
public class MessageConsumer implements Consumer {

public MessageConsumer(Channel channel) {
        this.channel=channel;
    }
public MessageConsumer(Channel channel, String type) {
        this.channel=channel;
    }

}
```

How to use spring to initialize MessageConsumer(new Channel()) and use in other class with auto-wired. 
How to initialize different constructor of the class.

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-bean-annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a new configuration class and define these objects as beans with the `@Bean` annotation. It should look something like this

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {
    @Bean
    public MessageConsumer messageConsumer(){
        return new MessageConsumer(this.channel());
    }
    @Bean
    public Channel channel(){
        return new Channel();
    }
}
```

If you want to further extend the class above to initialize different constructors of the same class. You can further extend the code to

```
@Bean(name="withType")
public MessageConsumer messageConsumerWithType(){
    return new MessageConsumer(this.channel(), "Some String");
}
@Bean(name="withoutType")
public MessageConsumer messageConsumerWithType(){
    return new MessageConsumer(this.channel());
}
```

Okay, so we have created two beans that create the same class but in a different manner. The two beans also have names. How do we specify which one we want to use ? For this purpose there exists an annotation called `@Qualifier`. What `@Qualifier` does is to specify which bean you would like to use when autowiring your objects. So for example if you want to autowire a `MessageConsumer` without a `String type` you would use

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("withoutType")
private MessageConsumer messageConsumer;
```

For a field injection and

```
@Autowired
public StringConsumer(@Qualifier("withoutType") MessageConsumer messageConsumer){
    this.messageConsumer = messageConsumer;
}
```

for a constructor injection.

Comment: if channel instance is passed in the method like public void m1(Channel channel) {}

Comment: I guess you can set the channel via a setter method. You can also try creating a MessageConsumer instance with the `new` keyword without autowiring it. It really depends on what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

Create a bean like this in a class

```
@Configuration
class ConfigClass {

  @Bean
  public MessageConsumer  createMessageConsumer() {
    MessageConsumer messageConsumer = new MessageConsumer(new Channell());
    return messageConsumer;
 }
}
```

Remove `@Component` on MessageConsumer class. it is redundant if you do the above.
Now if you Autowire MessageConsumer in any class, it will give you back the bean created in the above method(which has channel initialized).

Comment: i dont want to use @Bean as the channel instance is specific to that class instance. Dont want to create MessageConsumer with new Channel but with the one present in the class.

Comment: what do you mean by one present in the class?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried annotate your class with EnableAspectJAutoProxy and creating Bean with @Bean annotation?

```
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
```

Comment: How does this help? I have not seen any AOP reference in OP's question.